# jquery plugin caroufredsel hide next/prev buttons until mouseover carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

I am trying to make the buttons hide by default and they only become visible when the mouse is over. Although I am having problems where the carousel core code seems to be adding display block even if I set display none in the CSS.

```
var $slides = $("#slides");
$slides.find('ul.banners').eq(0).carouFredSel({
    height: 360,
    items: {
        visible: 1
    },
    scroll: {
        easing: "easeInOutSine",
        duration: 1200
    },
    auto: {
        delay: 1000
    },
    prev: {
        button: $slides.find('.prev'),
        items: 1
    },              
    next:{
        button: $slides.find('.next'),
        items: 1
    },
    pagination: {
        container: $slides.find(".pagination"),
        keys: true,
        anchorBuilder: function(nr) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"><span>'+nr+'</span></a></li>'; 
        }
    }
});
$slideButtons = $slides.find(".next,.prev");
$slides.find('ul.banners').hover(function(){
    $slideButtons.fadeIn();
},function(){
    $slideButtons.fadeOut();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="slides">
    <ul class="banners">
        <li><img /></li>
        <li><img /></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="pagination"></ul>

    <div class="next">Next</div>
    <div class="prev">Previous</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the plugin code?

Comment: its 4314 lines long so maybe best you download it from: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/

Comment: Did you see the Custom Events section , maybe it can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this way in css

```
 .next{
    display:none !important;
  }

  .prev{
     display:none !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that the most recent style attributes (ie. the furthest down in your html) are the ones setting the visibility to nothing. The style options added onto the tags are the most important I believe. Try adding the following to your tag:

```
<tag style="visible:0;" ></tag>
```

If this works then you know that this is your problem, this might work as a solution as the JavaScript will probably change the style later on mouse over for example.

If all your includes are in the header, moving your CSS stylesheet (the one setting the visibility to nothing) to come after the others might help, but if your JavaScript is included at the bottom of the page you might either have to edit the JavaScript or move it.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin is using sprite for the rollover effect. I think the quick fix is to photoshop the buttons to lower the opacity.

Answer (score 1):

You could try overriding the configuration. I added `display: none,` to your code. I haven't tested it though.

```
$slides.find('ul.banners').eq(0).carouFredSel({
    height: 360,
    items: {
        visible: 1
    },
    scroll: {
        easing: "easeInOutSine",
        duration: 1200
    },
    auto: {
        delay: 1000
    },
    prev: {
        display: none,
        button: $slides.find('.prev'),
        items: 1
    },              
    next:{
        display: none,
        button: $slides.find('.next'),
        items: 1
    },
    pagination: {
        container: $slides.find(".pagination"),
        keys: true,
        anchorBuilder: function(nr) { 
            return '<li><a href="#"><span>'+nr+'</span></a></li>'; 
        }
    }
});
```

Is your CSS stylesheet included after the plugin? You could try overriding via CSS and/or jquery/javascript after the plugin has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following piece of code:

```
$("#layout-main").hover(
    function(){
        $(".prev").fadeIn(500);
        $(".next").fadeIn(500);
        $(".pagination a").fadeIn(500);
    }, function(){
        $(".prev").fadeOut(500);
        $(".next").fadeOut(500);
        $(".pagination a").fadeOut(500);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code in css file.

.carousel .carousel-control { visibility: hidden; }
.carousel:hover .carousel-control { visibility: visible; }